# Unable to load/require file from Lua running from Atom in Windows

Tags: windows, lua, path, atom-editor, require

I'm trying to use Atom to run a Lua script. However, when I try to load files via the require() command, it always says it's unable to locate them. The files are all in the same folder. For example, to load utils.lua I have tried

```
require 'utils'
require 'utils.lua'
require 'D:\Users\Mike\Dropbox\Lua Modeling\utils.lua'
require 'D:\\Users\\Mike\\Dropbox\\Lua Modeling\\utils.lua'
require 'D:/Users/Mike/Dropbox/Lua Modeling/utils.lua'
```

I get errors like

```
Lua: D:\Users\Mike\Dropbox\Lua Modeling\main.lua:12: module 'D:\Users\Mike\Dropbox\Lua Modeling\utils.lua' not found:
    no field package.preload['D:\Users\Mike\Dropbox\Lua Modeling\utils.lua']
    no file '.\D:\Users\Mike\Dropbox\Lua Modeling\utils\lua.lua'
    no file 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua\D:\Users\Mike\Dropbox\Lua Modeling\utils\lua.lua'
    no file 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua\D:\Users\Mike\Dropbox\Lua Modeling\utils\lua\init.lua'
    no file 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\D:\Users\Mike\Dropbox\Lua Modeling\utils\lua.lua'
```

The messages says on the first line that 'D:\Users\Mike\Dropbox\Lua Modeling\utils.lua' was not found, even though that is the full path of the file. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The short answer

You should be able to load `utils.lua` by using the following code:

```
require("utils")
```

And by starting your program from the directory that `utils.lua` is in:

```
cd "D:\Users\Mike\Dropbox\Lua Modeling"
lua main.lua
```

## The long answer

To understand what is going wrong here, it is helpful to know a little bit about how `require` works. The first thing that require does is to search for the module in the module path. From [Programming in Lua chapter 8.1](https://www.lua.org/pil/8.1.html):

> The path used by require is a little different from typical paths. Most programs use paths as a list of directories wherein to search for a given file. However, ANSI C (the abstract platform where Lua runs) does not have the concept of directories. Therefore, the path used by `require` is a list of *patterns*, each of them specifying an alternative way to transform a virtual file name (the argument to require) into a real file name. More specifically, each component in the path is a file name containing optional interrogation marks. For each component, require replaces each `?` by the virtual file name and checks whether there is a file with that name; if not, it goes to the next component. The components in a path are separated by semicolons (a character seldom used for file names in most operating systems). For instance, if the path is
>
> ```
> ?;?.lua;c:\windows\?;/usr/local/lua/?/?.lua
> ```
>
> then the call `require"lili"` will try to open the following files:
>
> ```
> lili
> lili.lua
> c:\windows\lili
> /usr/local/lua/lili/lili.lua
> ```

Judging from your error message, your Lua path seems to be the following:

```
.\?.lua;D:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua\?.lua;D:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua\?\init.lua;D:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\?.lua
```

To make that easier to read, here are each the patterns separated by line breaks:

```
.\?.lua
D:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua\?.lua
D:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua\?\init.lua
D:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\?.lua
```

From this list you can see that when calling require

1. Lua fills in the `.lua` extension for you
2. Lua fills in the rest of the file path for you

In other words, you should just specify the module name, like this:

```
require("utils")
```

Now, Lua also needs to know where the utils.lua file is. The easiest way is to run your program from the `D:\Users\Mike\Dropbox\Lua Modeling` folder. This means that when you run `require("utils")`, Lua will expand the first pattern `.\?.lua` into `.\utils.lua`, and when it checks that path it will find the utils.lua file in the current directory.

In other words, running your program like this should work:

```
cd "D:\Users\Mike\Dropbox\Lua Modeling"
lua main.lua
```

## An alternative

If you can't (or don't want to) change your working directory to run the program, you can use the `LUA_PATH` environment variable to add new patterns to the path that `require` uses to search for modules.

```
set LUA_PATH=D:\Users\Mike\Dropbox\Lua Modeling\?.lua;%LUA_PATH%;
lua "D:\Users\Mike\Dropbox\Lua Modeling\main.lua"
```

There is a slight trick to this. If the `LUA_PATH` environment variable already exists, then this will add your project's folder to the start of it. If `LUA_PATH` doesn't exist, this will add `;;` to the end, which Lua fills in with the default path.

Comment: Thanks so much for your beautiful and comprehensive answer. I did change the path and it now works. But I still have two questions. (1) Why doesn't it work when I explicitly give the entire path? It seems awkward to have to add to the path for every project I have in different folders, though a work-around would be keeping everything in one folder. (2) Why does it list the actual path I used, but say the file was not found?

Comment: (1) Because the string you pass to `require` is then inserted into each of the path patterns. So when you use `require('D:\Users\Mike\Dropbox\Lua Modeling\utils.lua')`, Lua looks for the file `.\D:\Users\Mike\Dropbox\Lua Modeling\utils.lua.lua`. This file most likely won't exist.

Comment: (2) You are misreading the error message. The first line says the module name, not the path to the `utils.lua` file. The actual file paths start from the third line (the lines starting with "no file"). For example, if you say `require('D:\Users\Mike\Dropbox\Lua Modeling\utils.lua')`, then Lua thinks that is the module name, so it will list it on the first line, but the file Lua actually looks for will be `.\D:\Users\Mike\Dropbox\Lua Modeling\utils.lua.lua`. If, for example, you are in `D:\temp`, that path will expand to `D:\temp\D:\Users\Mike\Dropbox\Lua Modeling\utils.lua.lua`.

Comment: (I don't think colons are allowed in file paths on Windows except after the initial drive letter, so actually, `.\D:\Users\Mike\Dropbox\Lua Modeling\utils.lua.lua` would be an invalid path.)